# Installing PHP on different directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Is there any way I can install  PHP on an AWS EFS (shared drive)? whenever I install it goes to /etc/php/

I have seen people installing it to their home directory than to a separate file system.

I tried the following and couldn't make it work

```
INSTALL_ROOT=/ DESTDIR=/var/www/apache2 make install
```

Comment: what is your final goal? Multiple php versions?

Comment: My final goal is to have PHP installed on the shared drive. Currently its getting installed on /etc/php/<version>/ this is local to the system. I have created a shared mount on AWS EFS called /var/www/apache2. So even if one of the instances is down others EC2 instances will make sure that the service is available all the time.

Comment: I don't think using a EFS to share an apache processes is possible, I think you are using the wrong tool for the job. If you want redundant EC2 instances you should start multiple instances and run a load balancer

Comment: Thanks @MaartenDev. https://github.com/0xtf/HAMISPA - here they have used EFS instances. Also, the configuration needs to sit in the shared volume. so all the instances can access the same configuration.

Comment: That example stores the code in EFS? It does not seem to mention anything about apache?

Comment: I think you should only store application configuration and possibly code on a shared storage. Each search should have it's own PHP installation

Comment: This is  snippet which i need to put in to the shared storage esp the ${PHP_ETC_BASE}/apache2/php.ini. I don't mind installing PHP on all the EC2 instances under /etc/php/ but the configuration need to be there in the shared storage :). Your help is much appreciated                                                             installDepsPhp72 () {
  debug "Installing PHP 7.2 dependencies"
  PHP_ETC_BASE=/etc/php/7.2
  PHP_INI=${PHP_ETC_BASE}/apache2/php.ini
  checkAptLock
  sudo apt install -qy \
  libapache2-mod-php \
  php php-cli \
  php-dev \
  php-json php-xml php-mysql ...

Comment: Which step describes running that command?

Comment: The whole code is around 4000 line. So I need to edit it appropriately to fit into the AWS world. :) If I deploy it to one instance, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is the code also present in that repository?

Comment: https://misp.github.io/MISP/INSTALL.ubuntu2004/#2-install-lamp-dependencies

Comment: If I understand correctly these scripts are all scripts to configure a server, I think those scripts can be placed on EFS but have to be run on the EC2 instances. I don't see a link to EFS in the misp document?

Comment: the MISP github which i have shared is for single instances... i need to edit the config to fit in to the github - HAMISPA.

Comment: So the MISP works for EC2 instance, not EFS instances, these scripts have to be run on EC2. You could retrieve your MISP scripts from EFS, maybe that part is documented in the HAMISPA repository?

Comment: Yes, MISP uses EC2 instances for running the code. But the configuration is shared in the EFS. HAMISPA doesn't share any code which should have made my life easier. They have provided only the high level architecture. I am not a devops/sysadmin guy and first time using AWS. :(